# How to change the length of underline in TabLayout (Android Design Support Library )

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using Tablayout + ViewPager as the UI frame.
There is a underline of the selected tab in tablayout.the length of text and the underline length don't equal.I wanna them equal
How to do this?
Thanks very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change `tabIndicator` color and height like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@id/pages_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"/>
```

AFAIK you the tab indicator length is set to its tab width, you can't change only indicator size 
if you really want to change try changing ***tabWidth*** so indicator also vary with this change.

```
app:tabMaxWidth="30dp"
```

Comment: U're right.  It's feasible to set the tab indicator length by  changing the tabWidth ,but the UI is lack of beauty.  thank you very much

Comment: I wanna get a better A。If not,I 'll accept your answer.Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I have the same requirement. You can use

**app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"**

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
app:tabMinWidth="210dp"
app:tabMaxWidth="110dp"
```

Add just these two line of code in your XML. Its depend on your tab item. You can modified just increase and decrease both at a time.

[image: Check this picture]

Answer (score -2):

You can add another layout over tab layout and give padding accordingly.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@color/colorTangerine">

    <com.techlabs.oodhaar.views.CustomTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorTangerine"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorBackground"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBackground"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorBackground"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```